# How to pre-select facets (i.e. get selected checkbox on page load) using Django-Haystack?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-haystack, faceted-search, django-oscar

On the image below you can see how facets look when `cpu_producer == ""` (i.e. nothing selected).

[image]

There are circumstances when `cpu_producer` may be AMD or INTEL and on a page load appropriate facet's checkbox must be selected. How to select it in backend in order to get in frontend appropriately filtered cpu?

```
if category.slug == 'cpu':
    possible_sockets = '(socket_exact:"LGA1151" OR socket_exact:"LGA2066" OR socket_exact:"AM4" OR socket_exact:"TR4")'
    sqs = sqs.narrow(possible_sockets)

    possible_producers = '(producer_exact:"AMD" OR producer_exact:"INTEL")'
    sqs = sqs.narrow(possible_producers)

    cpu_producer = RECEIVED_VALUE  # "AMD" or "INTEL" or ""

    # I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS.
    if cpu_producer:
        sqs.PRESELECT(producer=cpu_producer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code digging led me to the file `haystack/forms.py`. It seems that the class `FacetedSearchForm` should be overridden.

However in my case it was acceptable just to have a url like:

```
<a href="{{request.get_full_path}}cpu/?selected_facets=vendor_exact%3AAMD">
    <img src="{% static 'logo/amd.jpg' %}" alt="{{ cpu_producer.title }}" />
</a>
```

which leads to the cpu page and because of the `?selected_facets=vendor_exact%3AAMD` part automatically selects Producer facet (i.e. AMD in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You may to use JavaScript. After page loaded get all GET-params and iterate of each checkbox:

```
function setCheckedItems() {
    var all_params = getQueryParams(); // GET params
    $.each( all_params, function( key, value ) {
        id = decodeURIComponent(key).replace(/\s/g,'');
        $('#'+id).attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
}
```